# Why is there no worldly punishment prescribed for dealing with interest?

Tags: riba, punishment, adultery

It seems that interest ( riba) was said to be worse than adultery. I am wondering if that's the case, why is there no worldly punishment prescribed for ones who engage in interest but yet adulterers are stoned?